# What is the operating system, intended to work with disks and able to wipe them?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, wipe

I've got Windows and Kali Linux on my laptop. I want to erase both of them in several keyboard prints. So, what I need is to wipe both disks data (obviously, without leaving the OS) (with using an operating system for this goal).
By the way! I want the drives to work after wiping the data because I will use them later for sure.
What've I tried:

> Ubuntu --> Try Ubuntu. After I decided to clean the disks from LiveCD Ubuntu, it didn't see the HDD with Kali.
> DBAN - Looks like it doesn't boot on UEFIs.
> Cleaning Windows disk from Kali Linux - it works, but for some reason, my PC still sees the Windows and even attempts the automatic repair.
> Cleaning Kali Linux disk from Windows - well, Windows doesn't see the disk at all. I think it's because of Ext4 filesystem.

A bit more information:
Windows is on 32 GB SSD, Windows 10
Kali Linux is on 500 GB HDD

Comment: After I decided to clean the disks from LiveCD Ubuntu, but it didn't allow me to clean HDD with Kali Linux on it. - What did it show/any errors?

Comment: Try  : https://partedmagic.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. Burn a Windows 8/8.1/10 image to USB
2. After doing it, go to your USB with explorer
3. Select any folder; I prefer "sources"
4. Create another folder with any name; I prefer "CLEAN PC"
5. Download AOMEI
6. Put the setup program into CLEAN PC folder
7. Boot from the USB
8. Click Shift + F10 before clicking "Install Now"
9. Type the following:

```
c:
cd sources
cd "CLEAN PC"
aomei_setupper.exe
```

9.1) The setupper name isn't the same! You can type `dir` before typing the setupper name, so you will see the actual name
10) Complete the setup
11) Clean the disks, finally!